# is it possible to do variant management in sap.m.table?

Tags: sapui5

We can do variant management in Smart Table

[image: like this]

Is it possible to do the same using sap.m.table

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cant.
ut:table and smart table enable it. But in sap.m.Table you can provide it in controller side.
e.g. with dialog fragment by pressing buttons